# AngularJS - ng-keypress not working for enter event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom-events, enter

In my project, `ng-keypress` is not working for <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key from all the places. From some places, it is working perfectly fine but from other places, it is working for all the keys except <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key.

Here I'm calling a `test()` method on the `ng-keypress`.

```
<div class="actions">
    <div class="ui approve button red" data-ng-click="test()" id="confirm-yes" tabindex="8" ng-keypress="test()">Yes</div>
    <div class="ui cancel button" data-ng-click="test()" id="confirm-no" tabindex="7" ng-keypress="test()">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

From test method, I'm just showing the key code. I could see the `keycode` properly for all other key presses except <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
$scope.test = function () { 
            alert('test called'+event.keyCode);
        }
```

I have gone through many Stack Overflow articles and I'm sure its syntax is correct, but I'm totally confused about its strange behavior.

Any idea why `ng-keypress` is not working for entering and it is working for all other keys.

Comment: It is not an event made for `div` you can try it on any input field like `textarea` or `textbox`.

Comment: He added tabindex for that div. hope it will work for div also.@ArpitMeena

Comment: Why are you not passing `$event` to your `test()` function?

Comment: Pass $event even though it is not working then Try **`ng-keyup`**, it is also behaves same like **`ng-keypress`**

Comment: Try input event instead of ng-keypress :p

Comment: I have added event code just to demonstrate the issue....just to check what I'm getting in the keycode

Comment: The problem is it is blocking only Enter key. Rest all are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I had to replace `<div>` tag with the `<button>` tag to solve this issue.
`Button tag` worked perfectly for this issue.

```
<div class="actions">
    <button class="ui approve button red" data-ng-click="test()" id="confirm-yes" tabindex="8" ng-keypress="test()">Yes</button>
    <button class="ui cancel button" data-ng-click="test()" id="confirm-no" tabindex="7" ng-keypress="test()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So you did not solve the problem, you created another approach for project logic, please remove the true answer check from this answer this is misleading

Comment: But for me ng-keypress is not working in angular 1 for button tag also.

Answer (score 0):

it could be because of another handler that invokes event.stopImmediatePropagation(): so far any other handlers are no called

you can check existing handlers for element in browser's Developer tools

Comment: do you have any useful reference for this event.stopImmediatePropagation()?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure for sure https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: I'm not 100% sure since it sounds weird to prevent all others handlers from being called; also there is a different case: angular invokes "ng-click" handlers if Enter is pressed when button or link is focused - so stopImmediatePropagation(if it's the case) can be operated there

Comment: in Developer Tools for most browsers you can set up breakpoint for specific event: so create one for keypress event and see who is handling that

Answer (score 0):

You are using same function **`test()`** for both ng-click and ng-keypress, try to replace with another function

```
   <div class="ui approve button red" data-ng-click="test()" id="confirm-yes" tabindex="8" ng-keypress="testcheck()">Yes</div>
    <div class="ui cancel button" data-ng-click="test()" id="confirm-no" tabindex="7" ng-keypress="testcheck()">Cancel</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan: I tried doing this also, but no luck. Do you know any scenario where the ng-keypress blocks Enter key, and allows other. In my project, at other places ng-keypress works correcrtly. But at some stage it wont respond to the enter key.

Comment: can you create a plunker

Answer (score 0):

I approached same issue with **ngKeypress** directive. It's especially interesting that on Angular's official example pressing 'Enter' is recognized.

Solved this problem using **ngKeydown** directive. It shouldn't make any difference when handling 'Enter' key.